Fiddler The connection to 'localhost' failed
[Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed.
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d).
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80
How to solve this problem?

I had the exactly same error just yesterday and found out that the listener on localhost port 80 had not started correctly and therefor nothing was listening on port 80 ;-(
